# calculate monthly rate of return on fidelity website

Tags: rate-of-return, fidelity

How do I calculate monthly rate of return for a particular investment account on fidelitys website.

I have couple of investment accounts and IRAs. I want to understand the change in the investments without the effects of my monthly direct transfers.

I don't seem to get monthly statement for investment accounts . where as my IRA does show a monthly  statement and well defined numbers of how much the investment vehicles changed in the month

Comment: Average monthly rate of return is the twelfth root of the yearly rate of return